# Elasticsearch Indexed Script Issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `elasticsearch 2.3.3`. I am trying to set up a template query using the following `mustache script`:

```json
{
    "from":"{{from}}",
    "size":"{{size}}",
    "query": {
       "multi_match": {
          "query":  "{{query}}",
          "type":   "most_fields", 
          "fields": [ "meta.court^1.5", 
                     "meta.judge^1.5", 
                     "meta.suit_no^4", 
                     "meta.party1^1.5", 
                     "meta.party2^1.5", 
                     "meta.subject^3", 
                     "content"]
       }
    }
}
```

I have successfully indexed this script as follows:

```
POST /_search/template/myscript
{


"script":{
"from":"{{from}}"
,"size":"{{size}}"
,"query": {
    "multi_match": {
        "query":  "{{query}}",
        "type":   "most_fields", 
        "fields": [ "meta.court^1.5", "meta.judge^1.5", "meta.suit_no^4", "meta.party1^1.5", "meta.party2^1.5", "meta.subject^3", "content"]
    }
}
  }
}
```

However when I try to render the template for example with:

```
GET _render/template
{
"id": "myscript", 
"params":{
"from":"0"
,"size":"10"
,"query":"walter"
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{


"error": {
  "root_cause": [
     {
        "type": "json_parse_exception",
        "reason": "Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n at [Source: [B@39f8927e; line: 1, column: 8]"
     }
  ],
  "type": "json_parse_exception",
  "reason": "Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value\n at [Source: [B@39f8927e; line: 1, column: 8]"


 },


"status": 500
}
```

The funny thing is I can successfully execute the script if it is stored as a file in the config/scripts directory of an es node.

What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: I think you're mixing up [search templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html) and [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) which are two different things. You're trying to store a search template in the `_scripts` index.

Comment: @Val Thank you. I have followed the directions at the link however the error still remains.  I will update the question Thanks